# In which file we have to write html code while designing wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new in wordpress and i don't know that from where html code is coming in wordpress theme and where to write html code.

Comment: login to admin panel and check which theme is active.

Answer (score 0):

The actual HTMl/CSS/JS/PHP/Others are stored in

`/wp-content/themes/[THEME_NAME_THAT_IS_ACTIVE]/`

on your server.

**HOWEVER DO NOT EDIT THESE FILES DIRECTLY**.

Have a read up on how to make [child themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), so that you can easily make modifications to your existing themes. If you modify these files directly, when a theme is updated, you will lose your changes!

Comment: I want to create my own wordpress theme, than also I need to create child theme??

Comment: No, you don't need a child theme :)